# Data interchange between Civil3D 2016 and QGIS 2.18

Tags: qgis, civil3d

Does anyone have examples of good practice for dynamic interchanging of data between QGIS and Civil3D?  Specifically, importing vector shapes from QGIS into Civil3D (and occasionally vice versa).

I am working on an engineering project which has a drafting team working in Civil3D, with our wider technical team using QGIS as a 'spatial sketchpad'. Often the design team will sketch out something e.g. an overall building footprint in QGIS and then pass this through to the drafters for further development.  We have been using the shapefile import facility in Civil3D but this has to be reimported every time a change is made.  Is there some format or database (GDB? PostGIS?) that could sit between the two software and dynamically update spatial data?

Comment: use the fdo connection. live connection to many spatial formats.